# Make TypeScript infer Type Aliases

Tags: typescript

I have a type alias that's a large union.

```js
type ErrorMsg = 
  | { message: 'oops', data: number }
  | { message: 'opa' }
  | { message: 'oopsie', data: string }
  | { message: 'ouch' }
  | ...
```

Now I'll have some other definition using ErrorMsg. For simplicity let's say

```js
type NumberValidator<E> = (n: number) => E | 'ok'
```

The problem is that when working with a `Validator<ErrorMsg>` TypeScript really likes to give me error messages involving this entire type union rather than the name of its alias unless I explicitly specify the alias in a manual annotation.

Is there any kind of trick that can make TypeScript "speak" in terms on the alias when producing errors and inferred types?

I'm just talking about the typical TypeScript errors looking like `Argument of type Validator<long, long list> is not assignable to type Validator<another long, long list>`, as well as giant types being present in the inferred types that appears when you hover over a definition in your editor.

Thanks!

Comment: Type aliases are literally that - a shorthand for a type. It helps with writing them down but they'd be expanded to the original. Not sure you can convert this to just a type name somehow. You can make the type alias to an interface, then you'd know the interface name `type Alias = MyInterface`, for example. But you're collecting a bunch as a union here. You might be able to use `extends` with inheritance to create a common and derived types, perhaps.

Comment: @VLAZ I did briefly consider the approach of defining `interface ErrorMsg extends TheActualUnion`, but this is not allowed (can't extend unions).

My best workaround at the moment is to simply wrap the union in a class. Then TypeScript uses its nominal type name, but this leads a bunch unnecessary inconveniences and I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Yes, you cannot extend unions but depending on the shape of your data, you might be able to have `interface Base { message: string }` them `interface Error1 extends Base { data: number }` for example. It's probably not always applicable but it's the only way I can think of to get actual type names.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] of code that gives you the too-long IntelliSense you're talking about?